# Is there something wrong with these simple java methods (filling a boolean array, checking if said array is full)

Tags: java, arrays, static

I have to write a program that figures out if certain people can buy certain pieces of land, represented by an array. To do this, I created another boolean array that, from the start, is filled with all falses. When somebody "purchases" that piece of land, this boolean array is filled with "true" in places where the land has been purchased. Hence, if another person would want to buy land where somebody has already done so, my program should know that this land is already taken.
However, I'm encountering problems. Are these methods written OK?

```
private static boolean IsItFree (boolean [][] boolArray, int y, int x, int h, int w) {
    if (!boolArray[y][x]) {
        for (int i=0; i<h; i++) {
            if (boolArray[y+i][x]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<w; i++) {
            if (boolArray [y][x+i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;


}
private static boolean[][] fillItUp (boolean[][] boolArray, int y, int x, int h, int w) {
    for (int i=y; i<y+h; i++) {
    for (int j=x; j<x+w; j++) { //mogoce minus 1
            boolArray[i][j] = true;
        } 
    }
    return boolArray;
}
```

the "land" is given with y and x variables that indicate array indexes where the land will start. H indicates how many spaces the (always square) piece of land should occupy vertically (down, 1 means only the boolArray [y][x], with no horiz. movement) and W is the same for vertical movement.

This is how I reference this in the main method:
`

```
...
boolean isFree = isItFree (boolArray, y, x, h, w);

if (free) {
    boolArray = fillItUp(boolArray, y, x, h, w);
}
```

Could the problem be that I'm referencing boolArray in fillItUp, because I'm using it in a static context?

Comment: Have you tried telling someone what problems you're encountering and asking for assistance?

Answer (score 1):

No, your code is not correct.
In your `IsItFree` you are checking wether or not some fields to be purchased are already purchased. But your current code logic only checks first if the fields along one axis are purchased and then checks the other axis, it does not check a mix of both. Visually your code checks only two sides of the rectangle but misses the other two sides and the inner area:

```
######
#OOO##
#O####
#O####
######
```

(no guarantee those are the *actual* sides which are getting checked in your coordinate system).

A fix for that is easy: you basically already wrote the logic in the `fillItUp`. Basically do the exact same loops but change the action inside:

```
private static boolean isItFree (boolean [][] boolArray, int y, int x, int h, int w) {
    for (int i=y; i<y+h; i++) {
        for (int j=x; j<x+w; j++) {
            if (boolArray[i][j]) // already purchased
                return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

Further notes:

- please name the method `isItFree` (starting with a lower case letter)
- no need to return the / an array in the `fillItUp` method

Comment: Thank you, this has been driving me crazy!

I'm not a native english speaker so I had to rewrite this part of the code and mistakenly capitalised the method name. However, I'm not understanding your second note :)

Thanks again!

Comment: @VidStropnik just dont return anything from the method - changes you make to the array inside the method are visible to the outside. There simply is no need to return the changed array and no need to reassign it outside.